# How to find if a block is finalized

Tags: proof-of-stake, explorer-api, beacon-nodes, finality, epoch

Is there a simple way to find out if a given block is **finalized** in PoS Ethereum?

Currently, I'm calling the endpoint `../eth/v1/beacon/states/finalized/finality_checkpoints` of the Beacon Node and it delivers me the **number of latest finalized Epoch**.

After that, I'm using the returned Epoch number to get all blocks using an endpoint provided by [**beaconcha.in**](https://beaconcha.in/) `https://beaconcha.in/api/v1/epoch/<epoch-number>/blocks` which **lists all the Blocks in that Epoch**

And the last step I do is check if the number of my block is smaller than the lowest blocknumber in the Epoch.

I'm looking for a simpler way to get that information using a library or the Beacon Node or execution Node or some API providers like Etherscan, Infura, beaconcha.in, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found another way using the latest version of Web3js 1.8.0. They added a new BlockTag that is called **finalized**.

```js
var Web3 = require('web3');

async function main() {
    const blockNumberToCheck = 15625164;
    const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<api-key>");
    const numberOfLatestFinalizedBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock("finalized");
    // console.log(numberOfLatestFinalizedBlock);
    if (blockNumberToCheck <= numberOfLatestFinalizedBlock.number) {
      console.log(`Block ${blockNumberToCheck} is Finalized`)
      return true
    } else {
      console.log(`Block ${blockNumberToCheck} is NOT Finalized`)
      return false
    }
  
  }
  
  // We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
  // and properly handle errors.
  main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
```

Comment: If there are other ways then please add them in new answer

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference to other people, if they are looking for cuRL requests, they can do it like so using Alchemy endpoints:

```
curl https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<apiKey> -k \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_getBlockByNumber", "params": ["finalized", false], "id": 0}'
```